# How to extend static function functionality in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that send the payment soap request but the thing is that so far I had only one bank in the system that I can make the payment. Now I want to integrate another bank. I have Bank model where I store banks(so far only one record now will insert a new bank). Here is my static function to sent the payment application:

```
static function sendLoanApp(BankTransaction $transaction) {

    $test = self::testXML();
    error_log('TEST: ' . var_export($test, true));

    $xmlReq = self::buildApplicationXml($transaction);

    $soapBody = self::getSoapBody($xmlReq);

    $soapHeaders = self::getSoapHeaders();

    $soapUrl = env();
    $soapBody = self::getSoapRequest($soapBody);

    //return $soapBody;

    $result = self::sendSoapRequest($soapUrl, $soapHeaders, $soapBody);

    if ($result['success']) {
        $parsedResponse = ApplicationResponse::from_soap($result['body']);
        if ($parsedResponse) {
            return $transaction->handleBankResponse($parsedResponse);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

now `$transaction` parameter has a `bank_id` which is stored on my db. The question is that now I have two banks and I want to extend this `sendLoanApp()`  I want to check  `$transaction->bank_id` to which bank it belongs I have a Bank model aswell. If `bank_id` matches my first bank then make a soap loan request to that bank if `bank_id` is the other bank then send to the other.

Comment: So what's the problem in finding bank by it's id?

Comment: no problem with that at all,but the thing is when I get that id how do I extend this function to handle two diff soap requests.@u_mulder

Comment: Can't you call this function once per bank? I understand that this works if you need to handle one bank

Comment: Perhaps static was a bad decision here. Usually you'd define a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) with `sendLoanApp` as the member and have a factory of sorts to instantiate the appropriate implementer based on what request you've got.